# Reducing a list of futures

Tags: scala, dictionary, future

I have long running function that returns a future as follows:

```
def longRunningFunction(signs: List[String], numOfWords: Int)
    : Future[List[(String, Int)]] = Future{ /* computation */ }
```

I need to reduce the output of the Future as follows:

```
val all = (6 to 24).map(i => longRunningFunction(signs, i))
                   .reduce(_ ::: _)
```

But this does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: *But this doesn't seem to work.* What doesn't work? Be more explicit. Also, `signs` is nowhere defined.

Comment: Signs is a just a List of Strings.

Comment: Your request is not clear.  Before the `reduce()` call you've got a `IndexedSeq[Future[List[(String, Int)]]]`.  What is it you want that reduced to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Future.reduceLeft(futures)(_ ::: _)
```

[Documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#reduceLeft%5BT,R%3E:T%5D(futures:scala.collection.immutable.Iterable%5Bscala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D%5D)(op:(R,T)=%3ER)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BR%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the thing you're looking for?

```
def longRunningFunction(signs: List[String], numOfWords: Int): Future[List[(String, Int)]] = ???

val all: IndexedSeq[Future[List[(String, Int)]]] = (6 to 24).map(i => longRunningFunction(signs, i))
val result: Future[IndexedSeq[(String, Int)]] = Future.sequence(all).map(_.flatten)
```