# How to efficiently combine future results as a future

Tags: scala, future

I have a lot of calculations contributing to a final result, with no restrictions on the order of the contributions. Seems like Futures should be able to speed this up, and they do, but not in the way I thought they would. Here is code comparing performance of a very silly way to divide integers:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object scale_me_up {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val M = 500 * 1000
    val N = 5
    Thread.sleep(3210) // let launcher settle down
    for (it <- 0 until 15) {
      val method = it % 3
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val result = divide(M, N, method)
      val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
      assert(result == M / N)
      if (it >= 6) {
        val methods = Array("ordinary", "fast parallel", "nice parallel")
        val name = methods(method)
        println(f"$name%15s: $elapsed ms")
      }
    }
  }

  def is_multiple_of(m: Int, n: Int): Boolean = {
    val result = !(1 until n).map(_ + (m / n) * n).toSet.contains(m)
    assert(result == (m % n == 0)) // yes, a less crazy implementation exists
    result
  }

  def divide(m: Int, n: Int, method: Int): Int = {
    method match {
      case 0 =>
        (1 to m).count(is_multiple_of(_, n))
      case 1 =>
        (1 to m)
          .map { x =>
            Future { is_multiple_of(x, n) }
          }
          .count(Await.result(_, Duration.Inf))
      case 2 =>
        Await.result(divide_futuristically(m, n), Duration.Inf)
    }
  }

  def divide_futuristically(m: Int, n: Int): Future[Int] = {
    val futures = (1 to m).map { x =>
      Future { is_multiple_of(x, n) }
    }
    Future.foldLeft(futures)(0) { (count, flag) =>
      { if (flag) { count + 1 } else { count } }
    }
    /* much worse performing alternative:
    Future.sequence(futures).map(_.count(identity))
    */
  }
}
```

When I run this, the parallel `case 1` is somewhat faster than the ordinary `case 0` code (hurray), but `case 2` takes twice as long. Of course, it depends on the system and whether enough work needs to be done per future (which here grows with the denominator N) to offset the concurrency overhead. [PS] As expected, decreasing N gives `case 0` the lead and increasing N enough makes both `case 1` and `case 2` about twice as fast as `case 0` on my two core CPU.

I'm lead to believe that `divide_futuristically` is a better way to express this kind of calculation: returning a future with the combined result. Blocking is just something we need here to measure performance. But in reality, the more blocking, the faster everyone is finished. What am I doing wrong? Several alternatives to summarize the futures (like [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192239/reducing-a-list-of-futures)) all take the same penalty.

[PPS] this was with Scala 2.12 running on Java 11 on a 2 core CPU. With Java 12 on a 6 core CPU, the difference is much less significant (though the alternative with `sequence` still drags its feet). With Scala 2.13, the difference is even less and as you increase the amount of work per iteration, `divide_futuristically` starts outperforming the competition. The future is here at last...

Comment: Futures won't help you here. They're not threads, they're essentially functions which get scheduled to run on a fixed thread pool. They're most useful when managed non-blocking IO, not for blocking CPU operations. For math-heavy stuff like you're trying to do, you need _parallelism,_ like what the Scala collections give you https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: That said, even parallelizing your algorithm may not give you a significant boost, depending on specifics, because parallelizing has a behind-the-scenes cost e.g. coordinating multiple threads.

Comment: You're likely to get much better performance by optimizing `val result = !(1 until n).map(_ + (m / n) * n).toSet.contains(m)`<- this creates quite a lot of intermediate allocations.

Comment: @ViktorKlang Have you read the comment below that statement, the asserts, the description of the example? I'm not trying to invent integer division, it's just silly code that can be parallelized.

Comment: Futures are surprisingly parallel to me: I implemented the real algorithm (the same kind of order-independent iteration, but useful and more complicated) in Rust and Go using channels and a fixed number of threads. The Scala implementation is a lot easier and more parallel when the average iteration has a lot of work to do, but lags behind when iterations are light. With "more parallel" I mean the parallel Scala implementation is twice as fast as the ordinary Scala implementation, whereas the parallelism-boost is less within Rust or Go (but there's plenty to be tweaked on all sides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you did everything right. I've tried by myself different approaches even `.par` but got the same or worse result.

I've dived into `Future.foldLeft` and tried to analyze what caused the latency:

```
  /** A non-blocking, asynchronous left fold over the specified futures,
   *  with the start value of the given zero.
   *  The fold is performed asynchronously in left-to-right order as the futures become completed.
   *  The result will be the first failure of any of the futures, or any failure in the actual fold,
   *  or the result of the fold.
   *
   *  Example:
   *  {{{
   *    val futureSum = Future.foldLeft(futures)(0)(_ + _)
   *  }}}
   *
   * @tparam T       the type of the value of the input Futures
   * @tparam R       the type of the value of the returned `Future`
   * @param futures  the `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable` of Futures to be folded
   * @param zero     the start value of the fold
   * @param op       the fold operation to be applied to the zero and futures
   * @return         the `Future` holding the result of the fold
   */
  def foldLeft[T, R](futures: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Future[T]])(zero: R)(op: (R, T) => R)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[R] =
    foldNext(futures.iterator, zero, op)

  private[this] def foldNext[T, R](i: Iterator[Future[T]], prevValue: R, op: (R, T) => R)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[R] =
    if (!i.hasNext) successful(prevValue)
    else i.next().flatMap { value => foldNext(i, op(prevValue, value), op) }
```

and this part:

```
else i.next().flatMap { value => foldNext(i, op(prevValue, value), op) }
```

`.flatMap` produces a new Future which is submitted to `executor`. In other words, every

```
    { (count, flag) =>
      { if (flag) { count + 1 } else { count } }
    }
```

is executed as new Future.

I suppose this part causes the experimentally proved latency.

Comment: I'm still too hopeful to accept this as the answer... Perhaps it helps to chain the futures, letting each one pass on the accumulated result?

Comment: @Stein of course ```.flatMap``` is a necessary thing to chain the futures. It is not good to block the thread by ```Await``` in the application due to ```ExcecutorContext``` exhausting. It is designed to be async and nonblocking. It may be slower is some single task, but when there are thousands of tasks it is more efficient in terms of CPU utilization.

Comment: Well this chaining is an act of despair, but you're most likely very right that blocking inside a future is a particularly bad idea. Performance is dreadful, >20 times slower (most of it kernel time). Therefore, blocking on `Future.sequence` is also bad. Relying on `andNext` to update a shared result logically requires blocking (for this particular example, an atomic integer would suffice). I'm still not clear exactly how `flatMap` does synchronization but I guess then there is no alternative.

Comment: @Stein ```Future.sequence``` is nonblocking. 
  ```/** Simple version of `Future.traverse`. Asynchronously and non-blockingly transforms a `TraversableOnce[Future[A]]`
   *  into a `Future[TraversableOnce[A]]`. Useful for reducing many `Future`s into a single `Future`.
   *
   * @tparam A        the type of the value inside the Futures
   * @tparam M        the type of the `TraversableOnce` of Futures
   * @param in        the `TraversableOnce` of Futures which will be sequenced
   * @return          the `Future` of the `TraversableOnce` of results
   */
  def sequence...```

Comment: @Stein, so ```Future.sequence``` is not bad. It is a worth doing approach.

Comment: @Stein ```.flatMap``` here is a monadic approach. It doesn't do any synchronization. Everything is async and nonblocking. Literally, it adds some code which will be executed as a new feature to flatten and map results from 2 futures (given and passed).

Comment: I added the sequence-based code I ended up with in the sample code, but its performance is much worse than the code I first posted. Not sure why I thought it does/needs blocking now. Maybe it can be optimized in itself, but there isn't much code actually.

Comment: @Stein may be. Your code with ```foldNext``` is fine. If you are going to have in production thousands of tasks as described one - it is the cost you have to pay for concurrency and similar performance for each task. If you use a blocking approach, you will face with service performance degradation upon an increasing number of tasks.